# How to change window center and width of an image on mouse move event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dicom

I have a `DICOM` image and i want to apply a **W/L** on the image. In normal terms, i am trying to change the color of the image as i drag the mouse over it. however it becomes completely white when i try to change it.

here's what I am doing.

this is just a part of the code.

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
var data = imageData.data;

var pixels = imageData.data,
    len = pixels.length;
var a = 256 * slope / window_width,
    b = 256 * ((intercept - window_level) / window_width);

for (i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
    //pixval = a * (pixels[i] * 256 + pixels[i + 1]) + b;
    //pixels[i] = pixels[i + 1] = pixels[i + 2] = pixval

    if (pixels[i + 3] == 0)
        continue;

    var pixelIndex = i;
    var red = pixels[pixelIndex]; // red   color
    var green = pixels[pixelIndex + 1]; // green color
    var blue = pixels[pixelIndex + 2]; // blue  color
    var alpha = pixels[pixelIndex + 3];

    var pixelValue = a * (red * 256 + green + b);
    pixels[i] = pixels[i + 1] = pixels[i + 2] = pixelValue;
    pixels[i + 3] = 0xff;
    //console.log(pixelValue == pixval);

}
```

here's the [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ne1pnaj/3/) with the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're changing your image data when drawing it.  You need to store a raw version of your image data, then "apply" your window level dynamically when drawing.  Otherwise, you're just compounding the changes on top of each other.

Try making two canvas objects: one (offscreen) to load and store your image data and the other to draw it.  Making this relatively small change to your code, it appeared to work right.

There may be other issues with your starting values -- I think you may be missing rescale slope and intercept -- but fixing the first issue should make everything easier to figure out.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ne1pnaj/5/

```
var imageData = ctxData.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
// ...
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
```

`ctxData` is the original data.  `ctx` is the drawing context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you please provide a JSFIDDLE code for the same. i tried using a tempCanvas object but i get the same output. the reason i am changing the imagedata while drawing is because i want the image to change its color as I am dragging my mouse over it. if i save the rawdata of the inital image and work on it, it will always give me the same output. I might be wrong but I am just assuming it. i would really appreciate it if you can please provide me a jsfiddle.

Comment: @Sushil I updated my answer with the jsfiddle example.  I think you were on the right track with `tempCanvas` (I saw the commented out line).  Think of it this way: rawData + window = displayData.  You can't overwrite rawData with the displayData.  What if you make your window width very small, then overwrite the original data -- all that precision is gone, you can't get it back unless you have a copy of the original data.

Comment: Thanks @whiskeyspider. Let me test it and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you @whiskeyspider for the jsfiddle. it works great. I made some changes to it as the calculation from my end was wrong. I created a new jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8ne1pnaj/9/. the only issue with is that for IE the W/L is not smooth as event.clientX does not give correct values.